# How to add one more item in object, which is nesting in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

for example:

```
track: [
        {
          date: "Date",
          delivered: 0,
          failure: 0,
          in_transit: 0,
          out_for_delivery: 0,
          partially_fulfilled: 0,
          ready_for_pickup: 0,
        },
      ],
```

In this array, on run time I have to edit it like

```
track: [
        {
          date: "Date",
          delivered: 0,
          failure: 0,
          in_transit: 0,
          out_for_delivery: 0,
          partially_fulfilled: 0,
          ready_for_pickup: 0,
          unshipped:0,
        },
      ],
```

How can I edit unshipped in last of the object and last thing I need to tell you guys this is not one object in array so how can I dynamically add unshipped to every object in this array?

Comment: Please may you edit your question to be more readable? Also please make sure the example is a [mcve].

Comment: just use map and add new key

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  {
    date: 'Date',
    delivered: 0,
    failure: 0,
    in_transit: 0,
    out_for_delivery: 0,
    partially_fulfilled: 0,
    ready_for_pickup: 0,
  },
];

arr.forEach((el) => {
  // if(condition){}
  el.unshipped = 0;
});
```

Or if you want to add multiple properties use: `Object.assign(el, {unshipped: 0})` to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const track = [{
  date: "Date",
  delivered: 0,
  failure: 0,
  in_transit: 0,
  out_for_delivery: 0,
  partially_fulfilled: 0,
  ready_for_pickup: 0,
}]

track.forEach(oTrack => {
  oTrack.unshipped = 0;
});

console.log(track);
```